# Only need to restore rep of one node in clustered Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Only need to restore repo([image]) of one node in clustered Nifi,but not all nodes?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, each node in a cluster has different data, so all nodes need to be restored.

Comment: @BryanBende thanks.i just know to choose PRIMARY NODE in PROCESSOR  would make this node the data different.Anything else?

Comment: Yes but it is possible for a new primary node to be elected if there is an issue